# Export column value from teradata as separate .txt files

Tags: teradata, bteq

im trying to write a code to export data present in column "task detail", and its export file name should be the same rows " task name " value

eg:

Task Detail      task name

task detail1     task name1
task detail2     task name2

the task details 1 ans 2 should be exported into separate txt files with task name 1 and 2 as the file names respectively

I tried exporting the task name values into a separate txt file first called input_filename.txt , then loop through it line by line, assign the line value to a variable and if the variable and task name value matches, export  the task details with variable name

code:

```
.LOGON 


while read -r line ; do

File_name=$(echo $line);


.Export data file=${PATH1}/${File_name}.txt, close


SELECT  Tasks.Task_SQL
FROM {DBAAAS}.Tasks AS Tasks
WHERE Tasks.Task_Name=${File_name};
.EXPORT RESET

done <${PATHH}/input_filename.txt

.LOGOFF;
.QUIT;
```

Im facing 2 errors,

1. expect something between start of request and while enter code hereKeyword
   2)Failure 3704 '{' ('7B'X) is not a valid Teradata SQL token.

Can someone please help me with what im doing wrong?

Comment: `{DBAAAS}.Tasks` is not valid for Teradata, do not put curly brackets around your database name..

Comment: Looks like you are trying to put shell commands / substitution inside a BTEQ script. You can't do that. You could use a here-doc to do substitution before passing to BTEQ stdin but the loop would need to be outside the BTEQ invocation.